# Rails - All test database opertaions hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was running a small migration to the test database (already run fine on local database), when it hung up. I terminated the process, and tried to re-run, I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot run migrations because another migration process is currently running.
```

So I try to reset the database, by running `rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`, but this again keeps running and giving no response. Desperate I thus try dropping and rebuilding the database, by first `rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test` that again runs forever and gives no response.

How can I get the migration to run normally again?

Comment: it sounds as if there's a flag set somewhere... and we can surmise it's not in the database. You'll need to dig into the ActiveRecord Migrations code to find the location of the flag. It could be in /tmp or it could be in memory (not likely, but a reboot will test the theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try restarting the test database to clear any connections.

Depending on the platform you're using:

```
brew services restart mysql
```

or

```
docker-compose restart mysql
```